# How to replace file link with a name during Safari/Chrome audio playback on home screen?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I have been googling for a while, and do let me know if this question is a repeat, but here's what I am trying to achieve:
I am making a HTML `<audio>` playback system, with help of [audio.js](https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/) library.
Audio playback is working perfectly fine, with some glitches in iphone, but when I playback on phone (Android or iOS), audio control shows up in phone's media player and home screen, which is a good thing but its showing the link to my audio, not the name of the file.

Here's what's happening:

[image: What's Happening!]

Here's what I want (taken from a famous audio playback website):

[image: Requirement]

Please, let me know what I am missing or if the question is incomplete or incorrect!
Any sort off comment or suggestion will be thankful.
Thanks

Comment: Guys, any comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think setting `title` attribute (on the `audio` element) to the string you want to be displayed, may be the solution you want.

PS: I'm inexperienced in SO so don't lay it all on me please, just trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the bounty, I'm pretty sure there is NO credible or official source for the accepted answer.

Official documentation on `<audio>` tag consistently makes no reference to the `title` attribute [MDN: <audio>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) as an example. And using `title` attribute on `<audio>` element will not result in any sort of magic behavior for typical users of the native api.

The author of `audio.js` also makes no mention of `title` in his documentation, nor any mention of it in his well-commented source code. Author of `audio.js` also does not use it in the official examples of module usage.

Two examples are provided by `audio.js` documentation that display song titles. [One of them](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html) uses an `<h1>` to display the title and [the other one](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test5.html) uses a `:before` pseudo-element. No sign of a `title` attribute anywhere.

The fact that suggestion to use `title` attribute answered OP's question seems to be a happy coincidence.

@sphinx

Comment: I agree, there is no official document that supports `title` attribute, but its working as required, maybe iphone's media player picks title as an attribute!

Comment: Yes, this seems to be iOS specific behavior suggested in [previous SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883200/use-mp3-metadata-or-html-to-display-artwork-and-track-name-on-iphone-lock-screen), but again it is completely [undocumented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)